# Tannakian category

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-schemes

Could you please explain to me what is meant by the notation : $ \mathrm{ad} $ that appears on the following link : www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/tc.pdf in the middle of the page : $ 36 $.

The level required to tackle this course on the link above is quite high. But the notation in question is part of the field of sesqui-linear algebra.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen of Lie algebra theory, I would guess that $\text{ad}(c)$ refers to the operator $a\mapsto [c,a]$, i.e. taking the commutator with $c$.

Comment: The course in the pdf above doesn't talk about Lie algebras infortunatly. :-D

Comment: No, but it does talk about affine group schemes, which are spectra of Hopf algebras, and in the present example, $c$ appears to be an element of a Hopf algebra. The notation ad is common whenever commutators makes sense, one such case being in an associative algebra, from which you can always make a Lie algebra.

Comment: I don't know. Thank you anyway. I'm waiting another one to confirm your idea.  :-D

Comment: The pdf above says that : $ \sigma^2 = \mathrm{ad} (c) $ and $ \sigma (c) = c $. Since : $ \sigma^2 (c) = c $ and $ \mathrm{ad} (c) (c) = 1 $, so : $ \sigma^2 \neq \mathrm{ad} (c) $, so that makes obvious that $ \mathrm{ad} $ isn't the commutator, no ? Thank you.

Comment: Where do you get $\sigma^2(c)=c$ from? I read $\sigma(c)=c$.

Comment: if $ \sigma (c) = c $, then : $ \sigma^2 (c) = \sigma (c) = c $, no ?

Comment: If you read ahead, on page 46, there is some evidence that this author means $\text{ad}(c)(x)=cxc^{-1}$, which to my eye is irregular usage of this notation.